# How to get event "wheel" in android

Tags: javascript, html, animation

I am trying to implement on my website the following code that I found in codepen: https://codepen.io/pmcgriff/pen/RWYBdb

```
window.addEventListener('mousewheel', function(e) {
if (scrolling) return;
if (e.originalEvent.wheelDelta > 0 || e.originalEvent.detail < 0) {
  navigateUp();
} else { 
  navigateDown();
}
});
```

however it does not work on android. Apparently the weel / mousewheel event is not recognized on android. How can I fix this?